# Shell Script: Get a SSH banner from bunch of systems

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to get a SSH banner from a bunch of systems. Unfortunately, I need to enter the password before the script can move on to the next system.

```
user@pc:~$ for i in {1..10}; do ssh 192.168.0.$i; done
WARNING:  Unauthorized access to this system is forbidden and will be
prosecuted by law. By accessing this system, you agree that your actions
may be monitored if unauthorized usage is suspected.
user@192.168.0.1's password:
```

Is there a way to ignore the password prompt and proceed to the next system in order to get the banner alone?

Comment: What if you disable keyboard authentication? I think with `-o PasswordAuthentication=no` or similar.

Comment: @Kamil `ssh example.com -o PasswordAuthentication=no 2>&1 | head -n -1` works, I think you should post it as an answer

Comment: To reduce latency, or just for fun, do them all in parallel with `parallel ssh 192.168.0.{} ::: {1..10}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable password authentication, that way ssh will not try to get the password from you.

```
ssh example.com -o PasswordAuthentication=no
```

You can explicitly disable all authentication methods to make sure, the `ssh` doesn't accidentally open a shell (thus block).

Or you can just `timeout 10 ssh` to make it exit after a specified amount of time.